# What are the official rules of Jenga?

Tags: jenga

Specifically, we are running into the following points of contention:

- When a piece is removed, do you have to place it neatly on top to build a new complete layer, or can you build incomplete layers?
- Are you allowed to remove and/or place tiles with both hands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange!

- You must complete each layer before starting a new one (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenga#Rules)
- Only one hand at a time may be used to remove a block; both hands can be used, but only one hand may be on the tower at a time. (see the [rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2452/jenga) at BoardGameGeek.com)

Comment: The box of my version of Jenga has a picture of a player using two hands to pull a block, despite the game rules inside the box clearly saying that you can only use one hand!